# How-to append data to a property in a Gson JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a program that returns the metadata of assets in json. Sample code:

```
com.google.gson.JsonObject assetMetadataJson = new JsonObject();
assetMetadataJson.addProperty(asset.getName(), new Gson().toJson(asset.getMetadata()));
```

The sample output for the above `assetMetadataJson` is:

```
 {"icons8-java-50.png":"{\"dc:description\":[\"desc\"],\"dc:format\":\"image/png\"}"}
```

We need to add more details to the same `assetMetadataJson` object's property. And that we have as another json string. Like this:

```
{"jcr:primaryType":"dam:Asset","jcr:isCheckedOut":true}
```

How can we inject/combine the above two json strings into one so the output will be like:

```
 {"icons8-java-50.png":"{\"dc:description\":[\"desc\"],\"dc:format\":\"image/png\"}","jcr:primaryType":"dam:Asset","jcr:isCheckedOut":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have `JsonElement` objects, it's quite easy:

```java
private static JsonObject merge(final JsonObject jsonObject1, final JsonObject jsonObject2) {
    final JsonObject merged = new JsonObject();
    mergeInto(merged, jsonObject1);
    mergeInto(merged, jsonObject2);
    return merged;
}

private static void mergeInto(final JsonObject destination, final JsonObject source) {
    for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : source.entrySet() ) {
        destination.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Or in Java 8 Stream API:

```java
private static JsonObject merge(final JsonObject jsonObject1, final JsonObject jsonObject2) {
    return Stream.concat(jsonObject1.entrySet().stream(), jsonObject2.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(toJsonObject());
}

private static Collector<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>, ?, JsonObject> toJsonObject() {
    return Collector.of(
            JsonObject::new,
            (jsonObject, e) -> jsonObject.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
            (jsonObject1, jsonObject2) -> {
                for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject2.entrySet() ) {
                    jsonObject1.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                }
                return jsonObject1;
            },
            Function.identity()
    );
}
```